# Android, XML: gravity = top won't work right (screenshot)

Tags: android, android-layout

this is an odd one:

I have this simple bit of code:

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_weight="600"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:src="@drawable/button_category_adventure"
                android:id="@+id/img_userpic_recview_comments"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

And receive this result:

[image]

Clearly, the imageview, is CENTERED in its layout and not on TOP.
Why is this happening?

This is the complete xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="12dp" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_weight="600"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:src="@drawable/button_category_adventure"
                android:id="@+id/img_userpic_recview_comments"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="3634"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_username_recview_comments"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:text="USERNAME"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_rankname_recview_comments"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:text="traveler"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_comments_recview_comments"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:text="Wow, that looks like it was so much fun and I don’t hate you at all for this! You look so pretty!! Right, this is actually me! HAHA! So, I guess I am the pretty one, am I not? ;D"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingTop="2dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="2dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="10"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="5"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txt_date_recview_comments"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:text="01.01.2020"
                        android:textSize="11sp"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:layout_weight="5"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/img_dots_horizontal"
                        android:layout_gravity="center|right"
                        android:src="@drawable/general_btn_dots_horizontal"
                        android:background="@drawable/ripple"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="536"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

                                                                                                                         Thank you all so far for the help!
```

Comment: go to design preview in android studio and check image width and size. I think image has space above and below

Comment: what type of image you are using ?

Comment: its a png that is a little bigger than the layout it is in. but that should not keep it from being set to center. and who the hall is downvoting everything here?

Comment: please check the image itself if it has spaces at Top and Bottom sides.

Comment: It is not about this particular part!!! where is your remaining part of xml?

Comment: post your cardview complete xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 try this and adjust your top margin.

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:layout_weight="600"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_gravity="top"
       android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/button_category_adventure"
        android:id="@+id/img_userpic_recview_comments"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: this actually was a good workaround. i ll check for more answers though but thanks!

Answer (score 1):

"Clearly, the imageview, is CENTERED in its layout and not on TOP. Why is this happening?"

It is not centered, it's on top, just like you have defined in the XML.

Answer (score 0):

Please note one thing:

When `LinearLayout` has orientation `vertical`:

Child View's `layout_gravity` could be `right, left,center,start,end`. Because you are already telling to `LinearLayout` to draw  child views vertically,So first child automatically will be at top.You don't have to specify top position.

When `LinearLayout` has orientation `horizontal`:

Child View's layout_gravity could be `top, bottom,center`.

For your problem, as I mentioned in comments. please check it in preview. I'm sure that Image is at top and white area is also part of that Image.